# libstdc++ crashing in ubuntu 64 bit

Tags: c++, linux

I have few GUI libraries compiled from RHEL6.2 system 64 bit machine. my task is to run it in Ubuntu 64 bit machines ..
so I tried it in 
Ubuntu 12.04.1 & Ubuntu 11.04
in both im facing a similar problem ..

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>   *** Segmentation fault
>
> Backtrace:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsC1ERKSs+0xb)[0x7f14e2728f2b]

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff5070f2b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff5070f2b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::basic_string(std::string const&) ()    from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

I cant compile it to my PC as the source code is not available with me . only libraries they gave to me ..
Can any one please help me sort out this problem ..

G++ version 
**g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3**

Please help me .. thanks in advance //

---

Thanks for the Reply ..

yes i cross checked both gcc versions

this is my host pc where im able to run my application

```
 gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
    Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



     ls -ld /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Apr 16  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.16
```

and the PC where im trying to run but not working is

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


ls -ld  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Apr 16  2012 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.16
```

both are precise Ubuntu 12.04

i couldn’t able to identify where my fault is. .

Please help ..

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 and 11.04 both use dramatically newer libraries than RHEL6.2.  Check the versions of stdlib.  I bet they're different.

Generally speaking you can't just pick up a binary (either a program or a library) and run it on another.  If you had a .rpm or .deb package you'd see that there should be version dependencies.

You may also be able to see which other libraries your libraries depend on by using ldd.